# Como juntar dois elementos de uma lista, sendo eles uma string e um inteiro. - Python

Tags: python, lista

Estou fazendo um programa em Python que lê o nome, idade e sexo de 4 pessoas. para isso criei 3 listas: `Listahomem`, `Listamulher` e `Listaidade`. Preciso retornar a idade e nome do homem mais velho, no momento só consigo mostrar apenas a idade do homem mais velho o nome não consigo.

Segue o programa abaixo:

```
listahomem = []
listamulher = []
listaidade = []
media = 0
mulhernova = 0
for c in range(1,3):
    nome = str(input('Digite o nome da {}ª pessoa:'.format(c)))
    idade = int(input('Digite a idade da {}ª pessoa:'.format(c)))
    sexo = str(input('Digite o sexo da {}ª pessoa:'.format(c)))
    if sexo == 'm':
        listahomem.append(nome)
        listahomem.append(idade)
        listaidade.append(idade)
    if sexo == 'f':
        listamulher.append(nome)
        listamulher.append(idade)
        listaidade.append(idade)
    print('\n')
print(listamulher)
print(listahomem)
media = sum(listaidade)/2
homemvelho = max(listaidade)

print('A media de idade dessas pessoas é {}'.format(media))
print('O homem mais é velho é o {}'.format(homemvelho))
```

Estou tentando concatenar dois elementos da listahomem, mas não consigo

Comment: Tente de outra forma, use um tupla que contém o nome e idade: https://ideone.com/CVwz3P - da forma que vc fez, está pegando a maior idade, independente do sexo (teste digitando somente mulheres, por exemplo)

Answer (score -3):

Já tens a lista de nomes e idades na mesma lista, imagino que o que precisa fazer é percorrer a lista pulando de 2 em 2 elementos. Algo no estilo do código abaixo

```
listahomem = []
listamulher = []
listaidade = []

media = 0
homemMaisVelho = []
mulherMaisNova = []

for c in range(1, 5):
  nome = str(input('Digite o nome da {}ª pessoa:'.format(c)))
  idade = int(input('Digite a idade da {}ª pessoa:'.format(c)))
  sexo = str(input('Digite o sexo da {}ª pessoa:'.format(c)))
  if sexo == 'm':
    listahomem.append(nome)
    listahomem.append(idade)
  if sexo == 'f':
    listamulher.append(nome)
    listamulher.append(idade)

  listaidade.append(idade)
  print('\n')

print(listamulher)
print(listahomem)
media = sum(listaidade) / 4

if (len(listahomem) > 0):
  nomeHomemMaisVelho = listahomem[0]  #Guarda nome do 1o homem
  idadeHomemMaisVelho = listahomem[1]  #Guarda a idade do 1o homem

  c = 2  #Percorre a lista a partir do segundo homem
  while c < len(listahomem):
    if (listahomem[c + 1] > idadeHomemMaisVelho):  #Se a idade for maior do que estiver guardado, substitui
      nomeHomemMaisVelho = listahomem[c]
      idadeHomemMaisVelho = listahomem[c + 1]
    c += 2

  print('A media de idade dessas pessoas é {}'.format(media))
  print('O homem mais é velho é o {}'.format(nomeHomemMaisVelho))
else:
  print('Não foram digitados homens')
```